# Meteor and Socket IO ports

Tags: node.js, meteor, networking, socket.io, port

I have included [this](https://github.com/Akryum/meteor-socket-io) to my project which allows to use socket io library in my project. I will post part of my code

```
 // Start server
  try {
    server.listen(8080);
      console.log("Server is litsnening for 8080 port");
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
```

So as you can see my server is listeneing for 8080 port. Problem is when I star my meteor app using `meteor` command it is started on port 3000. 
[image]
`http://localhost:3000/` So now how can I tell client to connect at 8080 port? It would be awesome if I could use same port however this is not possible. So how server is listening for connections? 3000 or 8080 port?

Answer (score 4):

I am a bit late but today I needed to implement socket.io in an meteor app and I wanted to used the same port for both

```
import { WebApp } from 'meteor/webapp';
import socketIO from 'socket.io';

const io = socketIO(WebApp.httpServer);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('new socket client');
});
```

This solution seems to works so far but I dont know if this is a good pratice.

Comment: Works great for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making confusion.
Using socket.io you will open a new listening port on your server, so your app will expose 2 ports, one for Meteor and another for socket.io.
First of all meteor now support npm packages so you can use directly the socket.io npm package ( so you will get last version).
If server doesn't log:

```
console.log("Server is litsnening for 8080 port");
```

I will check if you are actually including/running that piece of code, if you want to be sure if that port is open use `netstat` command that is available in all platforms (check parameters based on your platform). In Linux the command is:

`sudo netstat -lp`

Than in your client you have to connect to the socket.io server with something like:

```
var socket = Npm.require('socket.io-client')(url);

socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log("Connected");
});
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log("Disconnected");
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I never have this problem, can you double check your code which is starting the server? e.g. below

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
app.listen(8001);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, however I'm using meteor see https://github.com/Akryum/meteor-socket-io server example